# how can i load images in thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading

when i try to parse more than 15 picture from XML it required lots of time (Time consuming) to parse that pictures how to over come this problem ?

Comment: Use lazyload for your imageview

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to load images asynchronously, so for that i would suggest you to check this answer: [Imageview LazyLoading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012). I have already used this, its working fine me to load multiple images inside the listview asynchronously.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but this is too outdated as we need user user for storage permissions which may be inappropriate sometimes